# Undefined reference when linking stubbed library

Tags: c++, c

im trying to compile some c++ code that uses a stub library i wrote. The library is written in C and has a header and a few functions that do nothing. In my makefile i compile the library with

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -c myLib.c -o myLib.o
gcc -shared -nostartfiles -Wl,-soname,libmyLib.so -o libmyLib.so myLib.o
```

The library seems to build fine, running `ld -lmyLib --verbose` finds the library and shows all the functions. Note: is does give a warning:

```
cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
```

Then in my other code I compile and link seperately. I compile with

```
g++ -Wall -Werror -c foo.o foo.cpp -lmyLib
```

This compiles fine, foo.cpp contains `#include<myLib.h>` and myLib.h is in `/usr/include/`

When i try to link it all together with

```
g++ -o mainProg *.o -lmyLib
```

i get the errors "undefined reference to (functions in mylib)"

I have tried to figure this out for a few days but have had no luck. Is there something silly I am missing?

Thanks and let me know if theres any more info I can give.

Comment: Are your C functions declared extern "C" in the C++ header?

Comment: `g++ -Wall -Werror -c foo.o foo.cpp -lmyLib` FYI the `-lmyLib` does nothing there

Comment: I don't know what you mean by extern C, are you talking about in the library header myLib.h? Or in foo.h?

Comment: See [Language linkage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage), for C functions used by C++ code, say something like `extern "C" { void c_function_1(args); int c_function_2(other args); }`

Comment: @ben23f The library header will need to declare your C functions as extern "C", otherwise the C++ compiler will mangle their names.  A C library will not have its names mangled.

Comment: Don't use `ld` directly as you value your sanity.  Use `gcc` or `g++` (depending on which you use to create the object files).  The compilers add all sorts of extra options to the `ld` command.  Run with `-v` (`g++ -v -Wall -Werror -c foo.o foo.cpp -lmyLib` for example) to see what really gets run for you. The `_start` symbol is normally defined in an object file with a name such as `crt0.o`.  See also [Undefined references in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix).

Comment: And if you think you've got your startup code somewhere, you will need to tell `ld` to look for your start symbol instead of its default `_start`.

Comment: Hi @OlafDietsche thanks for the link. Wrapping the header file in extern C solved it for me. Interesting lesson learned about name mangling!